# Writing tests for file parser functions in a modular way

Tags: python, file, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I am writing a piece of python code which parses a formatted file into a python object. The file can vary, but for now I'm working based off a subset of what the file could be and hoping tests can help me to extend it for all of these files.

The file itself consists of a header containing metadata, followed by several data blocks.

```
[general header, describes length of header 1 & header 2]
[header describing data block 1]
[header describing data block 2]
[data block 1]
[data block 2]
```

Currently my code is outlined in the following way

```
with datafile as open(filename, 'r'):
    gen_header_obj = parse_gen_header(datafile)
    header1_obj = parse_header1(datafile, gen_header_obj.header1_len)
    header2_obj = parse_header2(datafile, gen_header_obj.header2_len)
    data1_obj = parse_data1(datafile, header1_obj.datalen)
    data2_obj = parse_data2(datafile, header2_obj.datalen)
```

Where each parse*(file) function calls file.readline() several times, depending on size of the specified data length.

Ideally I would have at least 5 separate tests, where I provide a fake portion of the file and sees if it gets the information correctly. Except in this case the portions of data are quite large (megabytes).

Would it be possible to write tests that resemble the following?

```
class TestParser(unittest.TestCase)
    filename = 'locally_stored_file.txt'

    def setUp(self):
        self.file = open(filename, 'r')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.file.close()

    def test_gen_header_parse(self):
        result = parse_gen_header(datafile)
        self.header1_len = result.header1_len
        self.header2_len = result.header2_len
        expected = ...
        assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    def test_header1_parse(self):
        # datafile.seek() is left of from test_gen_header_parse
        result = parse_header1(datafile, self.header1_len)
        self.data1_len = result.data1_len
        expected = ...
        assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    def test_header2_parse(self):
        # datafile.seek() is left of from test_header1_parse
        result = parse_header2(datafile, self.header2_len)
        self.data2_len = result.data2_len
        expected = ...
        assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    def test_data1_parse(self):
        # datafile.seek() is left of from test_header2_parse
        result = parse_data1(datafile, self.data1_len)
        expected = ...
        assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    def test_data2_parse(self):
        # datafile.seek() is left of from test_data1_parse
        result = parse_data2(datafile, self.data2_len)
        expected = ...
        assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    # Some code to force the tests to run sequentially as laid out above
```

As you can see I'm trying to write five seperate tests, which will hopefully fail individually if something breaks in the future. However I'm not able to test `parse_header2` without running `parse_gen_header` and `parse_header1` beforehand.

Not sure if there's a better way to approach this.

Comment: Can you change data file format to facilitate testing, or is it determined by someone/something else and you have to adapt your code to it? Because I would really advise to introduce some standard flags in file body to denote header/data blocks beginning and end, however this might be impossible in your case.

Comment: It's an output from an executable program, more specifically it's a formatted data file for neutron cross sections, in which the data format depends on several physical things (isotope, metastate, available measurements).

Answer (score 2):

it would be better if you declare all the lengths before hand and use the `seek` function to move the file pointer appropriately for each test. You can also use the expected lengths and test those

```
class TestParser(unittest.TestCase)
    filename = 'locally_stored_file.txt'
    expected_gen_header_length = 42 # The correct number it should be
    expected_header1_length = 42 # The correct number it should be
    # and lengths of the other things

    def test_gen_header_parse(self):
        with datafile = open(filename, 'r'):
            result, len_header = parse_gen_header(datafile) # output len_header if you want to do an assert for it
            self.header1_len = result.header1_len
            self.header2_len = result.header2_len
            expected = ...
            assertIsEqual(self.expected_gen_header_length, len_gen_header)
            assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    def test_header1_parse(self):
        with datafile = open(filename, 'r'):
            # Force datafile.seek() to begin after gen_header
            datafile.seek(self.expected_gen_header_length)

            result = parse_header1(datafile, self.expected_header1_length)
            self.data1_len = result.data1_len
            expected = ...
            assertIsEqual(result, expected)

    # and so on ....
```

Comment: Are you sure byte offsets in a text file is a good idea? Line offsets would make more sense, but since it's a text file (and thus potentially manually editable) I wouldn't trust even them.

Comment: Thanks, +1 because this is an approach I could take, where the expected header lengths etc will can be inferred from each test file. After thinking about it overnight I decided on using mock files, will post that answer later.